# How to use Powershell to pull XML values from an existing XML into a new XML document

Tags: xml, powershell, xml-parsing

I have an existing powershell script with the following code:

```
<Contact hideAll="false" hideCompanyName="false" hideEmailAddress="false">
</Contact>
```

Instead of the hard-coded variables, I need to pull from XML document, these values.

```
<HIDEONLINECONTACT hideEmailAddress="true" hideCompanyName="false" />
```

The current output is

```
<Contact hideCompanyName="false" hideEmailAddress="false">
</Contact>
```

FULL CODE:

I need the new output to have the same format.  but only show the variable (node?) if the value is true.
I'm new to powershell, please excuse any incorrect naming references.

ORIGINAL CODE

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="calcDate")]   
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
    [string[]]$files,

    #[string[]]$files = "input.xml",

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=2)]
    [string]$channelID = "4813",

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=3)]
    [string]$userNamePrefix = "SRC",

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    #[string]$saveAs='.\test.xml',
    [string]$saveAs='.\AC$(Get-Date -Date $date -Format "MMddyyyy").xml',

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [switch]$useScheduled=$false,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [ValidateSet("Exclude", "HS","something","somethingelse")] 
    [string]$defaultJobLevel="Exclude",

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName='calcDate')]
    [ValidateSet("InputFileName", "Yesterday", "Today", "Tomorrow")] 
    [string]$dateSource="Today",

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName='calcDate')]
    [string]$inputFileNameSpec="(?'Month'[01]?[0-9])\.(?'Day'[0-3]?[0-9]).
    (?'Year'(20)?[0-9]{2})\.xml",



    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='supplyDate')]
    [DateTime]$suppliedDate

)
BEGIN
{
    $editions = @{ 
        "36"  =  "acdc";
        "42"  =  "custcarefeb2011";
        "34"  =  "div1jan2011";
        "35"  =  "div2jan2011";
        "44"  =  "edujul2012";
        "43"  =  "energyjan2011";
        "39" =  "hcjan2011";
        "38"  =  "hcrnjan2011";
        "40"  =  "itdec2011";
        "37"  =  "nursejan2011";
        "47"  =  "salesmarketjun2013";
        "45"  =  "socnwtaug2012";
        "46"  =  "trucksep2012";
        "41"  =  "veteransfeb2011";
        "48" =   "manjun2013";
        "50"  =  "maxrecnov2014";

    }


    function IsValidBuyEdition([string]$editionList)
    {
         [boolean]($editionList -split "," |? { 
$editions.ContainsKey($_.Trim())})
    }

    function GetJob($AD)
    {

        $jobID = "SR-$($AD.ORDERNUMBER)"

        $encodedEmail = $AD.CONTACTEMAIL -replace "@", ""
        $encodedEmail = $encodedEmail.SubString(0, [Math]::Min(8, 
$encodedEmail.Length))

        $userName = $userNamePrefix + $($AD.CUSTOMERNUMBER) + "_" + 
$encodedEmail 

        $jobLevel =  switch($defaultJobLevel)
        {
            "Exclude" { "" }
            "HS" { "<JobLevel xxxxId=`"16`"/>"}
            "UnderGrad" { "<JobLevel xxxxId=`"10`"/>"}
            "EntryLevel" { "<JobLevel xxxxId=`"11`"/>"}
            "Experienced" { "<JobLevel xxxxId=`"12`"/>"}
            "Manager" { "<JobLevel xxxxId=`"13`"/>"}
            "Executive" { "<JobLevel xxxxId=`"14`"/>"}
            "Senior" { "<JobLevel xxxxId=`"15`"/>"}
        }

        $jobType = switch($AD.DOCVARS.JOBTYPE.ToLower())
        {
            "employee" { 1 }
            "temporary" { 2 }
            "contract" { 2 }
            "temporary/contract" { 2 }
            "intern" { 3 }
            "seasonal" { 20 }
        }



        $jobStatuses = @{"fulltime" = 4 ; "parttime" = 5; "casual" = 5; 
"perdiem" = 26}
        $jobStatus = ""

        $jobStatuses.Keys | % { 
            if (($AD.DOCVARS.JOBSTATUS -replace " ", "") -like "*$_*")
            {
                $jobStatus += "<JobStatus 
monsterId=`"$($jobStatuses[$_])`"/>
            "        
            } 
        }

        if ($jobStatus -eq "") 
        {
            $jobstatus =  "<JobStatus xxxxxxId=`"4`"/>
            "
            Write-Warning -Message "Job $($AD.adnumber) defaulted JobStatus 
to Full Time"

        }

        $industryTags = ""



        $industry = $AD.DOCVARS.INDUSTRY -split '#'

        $industries = @{
            "All"=0;
            "Agriculture/Forestry/Fishing"=1;
            "Metals and Minerals"=2;
            "Energy and Utilities"=3;
            "Construction - Industrial Facilities and Infrastructure"=4;
            "Aerospace and Defense"=6;
            "Automotive and Parts Mfg"=7;
            "Biotechnology/Pharmaceuticals"=8;
            "Chemicals/Petro-Chemicals"=9;
            "Consumer Packaged Goods Manufacturing"=10
        }


        if ($industry.Count -gt 1)
        {
            $industryTags = @"
                <Industries>
                  <Industry>
                    <IndustryName xxxxxxId="$(($industry | SELECT -LAST 
1).Trim())"/>
                  </Industry>
                </Industries>
"@            
        }
        else 
        { 


            $matchedIndustry = ""

            $industries.Keys | %  {
                if ( $_ -ilike "*$($AD.DOCVARS.INDUSTRY)*") { 
$matchedIndustry = [string]$industries[$_]}
            }


            if ($matchedIndustry -ne "")
            {
                $industryTags = @"
                <Industries>
                  <Industry>
                    <IndustryName xxxxId="$matchedIndustry"/>
                  </Industry>
                </Industries>
"@
            }

        }



        if ($AD.DOCVARS.xxxxxJOBCATEGORY.description.Trim() -match 
'^\d+$')
        {
            $jobOccupationCategory 
=$AD.DOCVARS.xxxxxOBCATEGORY.description
        } 
        else
        {
            $jobOccupationCategory =$AD.DOCVARS.xxxxxJOBCATEGORY.InnerText
        }

        $tempDate = $AD.SelectSingleNode("(./CHARGES/xxxx/STARTDATE)[1]")
        $date = if ($tempDate -eq $null) { [DateTime]$AD.SCHEDULEDSTARTDATE 
} else { [DateTime]$tempDate.InnerText }
        $ActiveDate = Get-Date -Date $date  -Format s

        $tempDate = $AD.SelectSingleNode("(./CHARGES/MONSTR/ENDDATE)[1]")
        $date = if ($tempDate -eq $null) { [DateTime]$AD.SCHEDULEENDDATE } 
else { [DateTime]$tempDate.InnerText }
        $ExpireDate = Get-Date -Date $date  -Format s

        $phone = $AD.DOCVARS.CUSTPHONENUMBER 

        if ($phone -eq $null -or $phone -eq "") { $phone = "1-111-111-1111" 
}

@"
    <Job jobRefCode="$jobID" jobAction="addOrUpdate" jobComplete="true" 
xmlns="http://schemas.xxxx.com/Xxxxx" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.xxxxx.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.xxxxx.com/Xxxxxx 
http://schemas.monster.com/Current/xsd/Monster.xsd">
        <Sites>
            $(($AD.BUYEDITIONS -split "," |? { 
$editions.ContainsKey($_.Trim())} | %{ "<Site>$($editions[$_.Trim()])
</Site>"}))
        </Sites>
        <RecruiterReference>
            <UserName>$userName</UserName>
        </RecruiterReference>
        <CompanyReference>
            <CompanyXCode>x$($userName.ToLower())x</CompanyXCode>
            <CompanyName><![CDATA[$($AD.DOCVARS.ONLINEFIRMNAME)]]>
</CompanyName>
        </CompanyReference>
        <Channel xxxxxxId="$channelID"/>
        <JobInformation>
            <JobTitle><![CDATA[$($AD.DOCVARS.JOBTITLE)]]></JobTitle>
            $jobLevel
            <JobType xxxxxxId="$jobType"/>
            $jobStatus
            <Contact hideAll="false" hideAddress="true" 
hideStreetAddress="true" hideCity="false" hideState="false" 
hidePostalCode="true" hideCountry="true" hideContactInfoField="true" 
hideCompanyName="false" hideEmailAddress="false" hideFax="false" 
hidePhone="true">
                <StructuredName>
                    <GivenName>Given Name</GivenName>
                    <FamilyName><![CDATA[$($AD.CONTACTLASTNAME)]]>
</FamilyName>
                </StructuredName>
                <CompanyName><![CDATA[$($AD.DOCVARS.ONLINEFIRMNAME)]]>
</CompanyName>
                <Address>
                    <StreetAddress><![CDATA[Street Address]]>
</StreetAddress>
                    <StreetAddress2><![CDATA[Street Address 2]]>
</StreetAddress2>
                    <City>$($AD.DOCVARS.JOBCITY)</City>
                    <State>CA</State>
                    <CountryCode>USA</CountryCode>
                    <PostalCode>$($AD.DOCVARS.JOBZIPCODE)</PostalCode>
                </Address>
                <Phones>
                    <Phone phoneType="work">$phone</Phone>
                </Phones>
                <E-mail>$($AD.DOCVARS.RESPONSEEMAIL)</E-mail>
            </Contact>
            <PhysicalAddress>
                    <City>$($AD.DOCVARS.JOBCITY)</City>
                    <State>CA</State>
                    <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
                    <PostalCode>$($AD.DOCVARS.JOBZIPCODE)</PostalCode>
            </PhysicalAddress>
            <DisableApplyOnline>false</DisableApplyOnline>
            <HideCompanyInfo>false</HideCompanyInfo>
            <JobBody>$($AD.ADTEXT.InnerXml)</JobBody>
        </JobInformation>
        <JobPostings>
            <JobPosting jobPostingAction="add">
                <Location>
                    <City>$($AD.DOCVARS.JOBCITY)</City>
                    <State>CA</State>
                    <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
                    <PostalCode>$($AD.DOCVARS.JOBZIPCODE)</PostalCode>
                    <Continent>NA</Continent>
                </Location>
                <JobCategory xxxxxId="$jobOccupationCategory"/>
                <JobOccupations>
                    <JobOccupation parentCategoryId="$jobOccupationCategory" 
monsterId="$(($AD.DOCVARS.OCCUPATIONID -split "#", 2| SELECT -last 
 1).Trim())"/>
                </JobOccupations>
                <BoardName monsterId="1"/>
                <JobPostingDates>
                    <JobActiveDate>$ActiveDate</JobActiveDate>
                    <JobExpireDate>$ExpireDate</JobExpireDate>
                </JobPostingDates>$industryTags
            </JobPosting>
        </JobPostings>
    </Job>
"@
    }

    function GetJobs($jobs)
    {
    @"
<nis:Jobs xmlns:nis="http://schemas.monster.com/Monster/NIS" 
xmlns="http://schemas.xxxx.com/Xxxx" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.xxxx.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.xxxx.com/XXXxxxx 
http://schemas.xxxxxx.com/Current/XSD/Job.xsd 
http://schemas.xxxxxxx.com/Monster/NIS 
http://schemas.xxxxx.com/Current/Extensions/NIS/XSD/NISJob.xsd">
    $($jobs | % { "
    <nis:NISJob>
        "
    ([xml]$_).outerxml
         "
         <nis:AdditionalProducts>
            <nis:Diversity desired='true'/>
            <nis:Autorefresh desired='false' />
            <nis:CareerAdNetwork desired='false' />
            <nis:Bolding desired='false' />
         </nis:AdditionalProducts>
  </nis:NISJob>"
    })    
</nis:Jobs>
"@
    }
}
PROCESS
{}
END
{
    $toProcess = resolve-path $files

    $toProcess |% {
        $currentFile = resolve-path $_
        $currentFileName = split-path -Path $currentFile -Leaf
        $atsWebPagDoc = [xml]((Get-Content  $currentFile).TrimEnd(0x1A))

        $jobs = @()

        $atsWebPagDoc.ATSWEBPAG.AD | 
            WHERE { $_.CLASS -EQ 2255 -and [bool]
(IsValidBuyEdition($_.BUYEDITIONS)) -EQ $true } |  
            #SELECT -FIRST 1 -skip 1 |
            % {

                $jobs += [xml](GetJob($_))

        }

        [xml]$jobsXML = GetJobs($jobs)

        if ($suppliedDate -ne $null)
        {
            $date = $suppliedDate
        } 
        else
        {
            switch($dateSource.ToLower())
            {
                "InputFileName" 
                {
                    if ($currentFileName -match $inputFileNameSpec)
                    {
                        $date = Get-Date -Month $Matches["Month"] -Day 
$Matches["Day"] -Year $Matches["Year"]
                    } else 
                    {
                        $date = Get-Date
                    }
                }

                "Yesterday" {$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)}
                "Today" {$date = Get-Date}
                "Tomorrow" {$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(1)}

            }
        }


        $saveFile = Invoke-expression "`"$saveAs`""
        #Out-File -FilePath $saveFile -InputObject $jobsXML.OuterXml -Force 
-Encoding ascii

        $jobsXML.Save($saveFile)

        #$jobs.outerxml
        #Invoke-Item $saveFile

    }

}
```

FULL ORIGINAL XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
    - <!-- Transformed by XXX Webpag with XXXXX.XSL v1.12 
      --> 
    - <XXXWEBPAG SOURCE="xxxx" CREATIONDATE="02/15/2018" CREATIONTIME="17:09" PUBLICATIONDATE="02/16/2018">
- <AD adnumber="1111111-11111-0">
  <DOCNAME>1111-1111-0</DOCNAME> 
  <CLASS>2255</CLASS> 
  <ORDERNUMBER>222222</ORDERNUMBER> 
  <CUSTOMERNUMBER>3333</CUSTOMERNUMBER> 
  <FIRMNAME>SOME NAME</FIRMNAME> 
  <CONTACTFIRSTNAME /> 
  <CONTACTLASTNAME>ATTN: SOMETHING</CONTACTLASTNAME> 
  <CUSTOMERURL /> 
  <CONTACTEMAIL>someboday@something.org</CONTACTEMAIL> 
  <LOCATIONFAX /> 
  <CUSTOMERBILLADDRESS1>Some Address</CUSTOMERBILLADDRESS1> 
  <CUSTOMERCITY>Sometown</CUSTOMERCITY> 
  <CUSTOMERSTATE>SomeState</CUSTOMERSTATE> 
  <CUSTOMERZIP>11111</CUSTOMERZIP> 
  <CLASSDESCRIPTION>Some Description</CLASSDESCRIPTION> 
  <EDITIONID>34</EDITIONID> 
  <STARTDATE>02/16/2018</STARTDATE> 
  <SCHEDULEDSTARTDATE>01/21/2018</SCHEDULEDSTARTDATE> 
  <ENDDATE>02/17/2018</ENDDATE> 
  <SCHEDULEENDDATE>02/19/2018</SCHEDULEENDDATE> 
  <SORTKEY>KEYOFSOMESORT</SORTKEY> 
  <BUYEDITIONS>11,34,45</BUYEDITIONS> 
- <CHARGES>
  <CHARGE id="BLD2">BLD2</CHARGE> 
  <CHARGE id="BRD1">BRD1</CHARGE> 
- <!-- Original charge was EMB1
  --> 
- <XXXXX id="XXXXX" rundays="30">
  <STARTDATE>01/21/2018</STARTDATE> 
  <ENDDATE>02/20/2018</ENDDATE> 
  </XXXXX>
  <CAJ id="CAJ">1</CAJ> 
  <CHARGE id="MBOLD">MBOLD</CHARGE> 
  <CHARGE id="LOGO">LOGO</CHARGE> 
  </CHARGES>
  <BILLSOURCE>Liner</BILLSOURCE> 
  <BUYTYPE>0217</BUYTYPE> 
  <PUBCODE>Xxxx</PUBCODE> 
- <WEBEDITIONS>
  <WEBEDITION>11</WEBEDITION> 
  </WEBEDITIONS>
- <DOCVARS>
  <AGENCY>0</AGENCY> 
  <CUSTPHONENUMBER>707-111-1111</CUSTPHONENUMBER> 
  <HIDEONLINECONTACT hideEmailAddress="true" hideCompanyName="true" /> 
  <INDUSTRY>XXXX#11</INDUSTRY> 
  <JOBCITY>SomeCity</JOBCITY> 
  <JOBSTATUS>Relief</JOBSTATUS> 
  <JOBTITLE>Senior Assitant</JOBTITLE> 
  <JOBTYPE>Employee</JOBTYPE> 
  <JOBZIPCODE>111111</JOBZIPCODE> 
  <xxxxxxJOBCATEGORY description="Other">11</xxxxxxJOBCATEGORY> 
  <OCCUPATIONID>Other#11892</OCCUPATIONID> 
  <ONLINEFIRMNAME>FirmName</ONLINEFIRMNAME> 
  <RESPONSEEMAIL>someone@somthing.com</RESPONSEEMAIL> 
  <RESPONSEPHONE>111-111-1111</RESPONSEPHONE> 
  <SALARY>$00</SALARY> 
  </DOCVARS>
- <IMAGES>
  <IMAGE sourcepath="\\xxxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\1111\111 1 column color-8.gif" /> 
  </IMAGES>
- <ADTEXT>
- <![CDATA[ 
Extra-help

$11.11 - $22.22/hour
Apply Now

To view position details,
benefits, & apply online, visit www.something.com
or call HR, 1111-1111-1111. EOE

  ]]> 
  </ADTEXT>
  </AD>
```

Comment: Please post the actual code

Comment: there is a lot of code, too long for the allowed characters.  I'll edit original with full code.

Comment: @sbates Given your samples at the top, is the desired output: `<Contact hideAll="false" hideCompanyName="true" hideEmailAddress="true">
</Contact>`?

Comment: I don't need to see the hideAll node at all.  if either of the other two are true in the input file I would want to see them with "true".  If the node is not in the input file then I would not want to see that node in the output file.  So, if the input file only showed the hideEmailAddress then I would want to see only the hideEmailAddress.  The file could contain both, one, or all.  Does that make sense?

Comment: It would be helpful to know if this is even possible.  thanks,

Comment: OK, I've gotten to a point where the tags are coming in.  I'm using this code

Comment: OK, I've gotten to a point where the tags are coming in.  I'm using this code     <Contact> <HideContactName>$($AD.DOCVARS.HIDEONLINECONTACT.hideContactName)</HideContactName>
<HideEmailAddress>$($AD.DOCVARS.HIDEONLINECONTACT.HideEmailAddress)</HideEmailAddress>
<HideCompanyName>$($AD.DOCVARS.HIDEONLINECONTACT.hideCompanyName)
</HideCompanyName>
<HideFax>$($AD.DOCVARS.HIDEONLINECONTACT.hideFax)</HideFax>
<HideContactAddress>$($AD.DOCVARS.HIDEONLINECONTACT.ContactAddress)</HideContactAddress>   Now I need to understand how to NOT bring in the tags if they are not in the original document

Comment: Now I just need to understand how to create an 'if' statement so that the tags are only brought in if there is a tag in the original document